# Позиционирование на нужное id в DBLookupComBox

Tags: delphi, firebird

Доброе время суток,
Такой вопрос:
Есть таблица1 с тремя полями

```
«id» «last_name» «firm»
 1     Федотов   фирма №3
 2     Федотов   фирма №4
```

с которой берет данные *DBLookupComBox*.
В параметрах «ListField» и «KeyField» (*DBLookupComBox*), установлено поле «last_name». При перемещении по списку *DBLookupComBox*, в *DBGrid* таблица1 видно, что курсор перемещается по записям (1 и 2).
Как сделать чтоб пользователь при выборе фамилии например

с "id" = 1, курсор мог позиционироваться на выбранную запись, с id = 1,
или
с "id" = 2, курсор мог позиционироваться на выбранную запись, с id = 2.

**А не только на запись, с id = 1**?

Сейчас, при выборе разных строк в *DBLookupComBox*, позиционирование происходит все время на запись с id = 1.

Спасибо

Comment: вроде нужно `KeyField` указать `id`

Comment: "id" - укзывается, если прямая ссылка идет.  

У меня же, *DBLookupComBox* используется как справочник, т.е. тлько чтоб в поле вставить нужное строковое значение

Comment: значение last_name одинаково, и поэтому так и будет. Может использовать last_name+firm. так как по другому с DBLookupComBox не получтся. или сделать этот DBLookup с компонентой DBGrid

Comment: А может можно каким-нибудь образом в список 'id' цеплять? Или формировать согласованный с списком массив 'id'? А при выборе строки из списка, (я наверное могу узнать ее порядковый номер), а далее брать 'id' из массива?

Comment: или например, без всякого массива, узнаю номер выбранной строки в *dblookupcombobox* и иду на этот же номер строки в *DatatSet*

Comment: можно и так. в собитие это установить и все.

Comment: А не подскажите, как узнать номер индекса выбранной строки в *dblookupcomboboxEh*? Это же не *ComboBox*, тут *ItemIndex* - нет. Сейчас ищу в сети, что не попадается.

Comment: есть еще вариант. указать   `ListFields := 'last_name; firm';` тогда id дожно менятся на 2

Comment: Да действительно помогло. - еще раз спасибо. Только указывать нужно в  **"KeyField" := 'last_name; ID'**; А *ListFields* оставить как есть, иначе, значение поля *firm* лезет в список. 
Все пока замечательно работает :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из обсуждений нашли ответ.

```
"KeyField" := 'last_name; ID';
```

KeyField - это поле, которое будет вставляться в DataField